# Why terminated instance is still showing in GlobalVIew?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I terminated some Amazon EC2 instances.

However, they are still appearing in the list of instances in the E2 management console.

How can I remove them?

Comment: Are you saying that you have an Amazon EC2 instance that was terminated, and you are asking why it is still showing in the EC2 management console? Terminated instances will show in the console for a while (I think 6 hours?) and will then disappear.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Is there a way to make terminated instances disappear immediately?

Comment: @ÖmerAn Yes, you can modify the **filter** on the list of instances. When configured to only display `State = Running`, then terminated instances will not appear.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Then `Stopped` instances will also be filtered out. What I want to do is to permanently disable the visibility of `Terminated` instances rather than applying filters.

Comment: @ÖmerAn You can specify multiple filters (eg show Running _and_ Stopped). It is not possible to permanently modify what is displayed, but you can create a **bookmark** from the URL and quickly return to it in future. The bookmark URL will include the requested filters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This message is temporary.
After a while it will disappear.

Comment: OK, I see that  disappeared now, but is very confusing.
Anyway this GlobalVIew option was not available 1 year ago, right ? 
Finaly option how to check paid services across all AWS.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to remove `Terminated` instances immediately, as this is imposed by AWS.

Answer (score 1):

Terminated instances remain visible after termination (for approximately one hour).

By default, Amazon EC2 deletes all EBS volumes that were attached when the instance launched. Volumes attached after instance launch continue running.

You can see instance count is 1.
[image: You can see instance count is 1]

After 1 hour instance is gone.
[image]

[Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/terminate-instances.html#:%7E:text=Terminated%20instances%20remain%20visible%20after,and%20terminate%20EBS%2Dbacked%20instances.)